# Why is the preimage of a Spec $A$ the Spec of its integral closure in a morphism of curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $\phi:X\to Y$ be a morphism of nonsigular complete curves. Let Spec $A:=U\subset Y$ be an open set. Why is $\phi^{-1} (U) =$ Spec $B$, the spectrum of the integral closure of $A$ in $K(X)$? Can we weaken the hypothesis of nonsingularity and completeness?

This statement is, for example, in Hartshorne II.6.8. I see the containment $\phi^{-1} U \subset$ Spec $B$, but how do I prove the other one? How do I finish the following argument (is this the way to think about it?)?

Every point $p\in \phi^{-1}(U)$ is such that the local ring $\mathcal O_{Y,q}$ of some $q\in U$ dominates $\mathcal O_{X,p}$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your morphism has to be dominant, otherwise the conclusion may be false. In this case the morphism is certainly proper because $Y$ is separated and $X/k$ is.
So the pre-image of a point is a finite set and your morphism is quasi-finite, but a proper quasi finite morphism is finite.
The non-singularity hypothesis is thus not needed.

Now you can also finish Harsthorne's argument (which doesn't seem natural to me) in the following manner. As $\text{Spec }B$ is isomorphic to an open subset of $X$ say $V$, that is mapped to $U$, you certainly have $V\subset \phi^{-1}(U)$. The other inclusion is given by the fact that if $X\to Y$ is a dominant morphism with $X$ normal and $Y$ integral (which is your case) then it factorises through the normalisation of $Y$ in an extension of its function field.

On the algebraic side let $R=O_X(\phi^{-1}(U))$ then $R$ is normal in $K(X)$, finite over $A$, thus it is $B$, as $\text{Spec }B$ is a subset of $\phi^{-1}(U)$ they must be equal.

Comment: Wow! thank you for your detailed answer. Let me see if I followed everything 1) in "because $Y$ is separated and $X/k$ is..." do you mean to say "...proper"? 2) Finite implies that $\phi^{-1} (U)$ is the spectrum of an integral ring over $A$, say Spec $B'$. Since Spec $B$ is the normalization of Spec $A$ in the finite field extension $K(X)/K(Y)$ we get the morphism Spec $B' \to$ Spec $B$. This implies that $R=O_X(\phi^{-1}(U))$ is normal in $K(X)$.

Comment: I believe Hartshorne just wanted to avoid using ZMT.

Comment: 1/ Yes I mean $X\to Y$ is proper because $X/k$ is (proper).

Comment: 2/ The fact that $R$ is normal in $K(X)$ resultats simply from the fact that $X$ is non-singular, and thus normal (because regular local rings are UFD and thus normal). I'm not really sure to understand what you're saying in your part 2/.
Just to be clear, I gave in my message two indepedant proofs of your claim, one using Zariski Main Theorem, and the other filling in Harsthorne's blanks. So i do not use the fact that $X\to Y$ is finite in my second proof.

Comment: Dear @A.Rodriguez, If you aren't using that $f$ is finite in the second proof, how do you know (a) that $\phi^{-1}(U)$ is affine, and (b) that its ring of global sections is finite over $A$?